# Switch Case in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

I want to do multiple update table in SQL Server 2012 using switch case

Here is my query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deactivateRecord
    @paraTableName varchar(15),
    @paraID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select 
        case @paraTableName when 'UserMaster' then update UserMaster set IsActive=1 where UserID=@paraID
     case @paraTableName when  'GroupMaster' then update GroupMaster set IsActive=1 where GRoupID=@paraID


END
GO
```

Where am I going wrong? Help me out .

Comment: you left the end.
 case @paraTableName when  'UserMaster' then update UserMaster set IsActive=1 where UserID=@paraID END

Comment: @PeterRing, it's not sufficient to add the END clause, as it's not possible to have an UPDATE statement inside a SELECT statement. See my answer below.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **NOT** designed to handle program flow - use `IF` instead. `CASE` is an **expression** that can return one or another atomic value - but it **cannot** contain code blocks

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deactivateRecord 

    @paraTableName varchar(15),
    @paraID int

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.UserMaster
    SET IsActive = 1
    WHERE UserID = @paraID
        AND @paraTableName = 'UserMaster'

    UPDATE dbo.GroupMaster
    SET IsActive = 1
    WHERE GRoupID = @paraID
        AND @paraTableName = 'GroupMaster'

END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to read out your code, after a particular case is resolved? For example, if @paraTableName = 'UserMaster', your code would resolve like this (ignoring the fact that your `CASE` statement didn't have an `END` clause, and that CASE statements in T-SQL cannot contain code blocks - only atomic values):

```
select update UserMaster set IsActive=1 where UserID=@paraID
```

This obviously makes no sense, since you cannot have an `UPDATE` statement inside a `SELECT` statement.

Since you're inside a Stored Procedure, rewrite your code to something like this instead:

```
IF @paraTableName = 'UserMaster'
    update UserMaster set IsActive=1 where UserID=@paraID
IF @paraTableName = 'GroupMaster'
    update GroupMaster set IsActive=1 where GRoupID=@paraID
```